# Translate Pandas merge to Dask

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dask

I am trying to perform a somewhat involved operation on a dataframe involving grouping and operations on numpy arrays. I can get the operation to work in Pandas, but the equivalent code in Dask gives me an error that I haven't figured out how to work around.

I have two kinds of items in my dataframe: shapes and colors. Each item is associated with a vector represented as a numpy array.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy import array
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
from numpy import mean as array_mean


p = DataFrame({
    "type": ["shape", "shape", "color", "color", "color"],
    "vector": [array([1.0, 1.1]),
                  array([0.8, 0.9]),
                  array([0.6, 0.8]),
                  array([1.1, 1.2]),
                  array([0.7, 0.9])                  
                 ]
})


    type    vector
0   shape   [1.0, 1.1]
1   shape   [0.8, 0.9]
2   color   [0.6, 0.8]
3   color   [1.1, 1.2]
4   color   [0.7, 0.9]
```

I want to do the following:

1. Group the items by type.
2. Take the mean vector for each group.
3. For each item, calculate the cosine distance of its vector to its group's mean and sort within the group by this distance.

The following function accomplishes this with Pandas.

```
def pandas_ordering(f):
    means = f.groupby("type")["vector"].apply(array_mean).to_frame().rename(columns={"vector":"mean"})
    f = f.merge(means, left_on="type", right_index=True)
    f["cosine distance"] = f.apply(lambda row:cosine(row["vector"], row["mean"]), axis=1)
    return f.groupby("type", group_keys=False).apply(lambda x:x.sort_values("cosine distance"))

pandas_ordering(p)

    type    vector       mean                                       cosine distance
4   color   [0.7, 0.9]  [0.8000000000000002, 0.9666666666666667]    0.000459
2   color   [0.6, 0.8]  [0.8000000000000002, 0.9666666666666667]    0.001144
3   color   [1.1, 1.2]  [0.8000000000000002, 0.9666666666666667]    0.001280
0   shape   [1.0, 1.1]  [0.9, 1.0]                               0.000012
1   shape   [0.8, 0.9]  [0.9, 1.0]                               0.000019
```

I rewrote the function in Dask. The logic is identical, and the code is almost identical except for a couple of `meta` decorations.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

f = dd.from_pandas(p, npartitions=1)

def dask_ordering(f):
    means = f.groupby("type")["vector"].apply(array_mean, meta="object").to_frame().rename(columns={0:"mean"})
    f = f.merge(means, left_on="type", right_index=True)
    f["cosine distance"] = f.apply(lambda row:cosine(row["vector"], row["mean"]), axis=1, meta="object")
    f.groupby("type", group_keys=False).apply(lambda x:x.sort_values("cosine distance"), meta="object")
    return f
```

However, the Dask version gives an error when it tries to merge the frame of means with the original frame of vectors.

```
dask_ordering(f).compute()

  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-120-46dd96a5db68> in <module>
  ----> 1 dask_ordering(f).compute()

  <ipython-input-119-49ddda5479b1> in dask_ordering(f)
        5 def dask_ordering(f):
        6     means = f.groupby("type")["vector"].apply(array_mean, meta="object").to_frame().rename(columns={0:"mean"})
  ----> 7     f = f.merge(means, left_on="type", right_index=True)
        8     f["cosine distance"] = f_1.apply(lambda row:cosine(row["vector"], row["mean"]), axis=1, meta="object")
        9     f.groupby("type", group_keys=False).apply(lambda x:x.sort_values("cosine distance"), meta="object")

  ~/Documents/notebooks/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py in merge(self, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, suffixes, indicator, npartitions, shuffle)
     3768             npartitions=npartitions,
     3769             indicator=indicator,
  -> 3770             shuffle=shuffle,
     3771         )
     3772 

  ~/Documents/notebooks/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/multi.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, suffixes, indicator, npartitions, shuffle, max_branch)
      490             right_index=right_index,
      491             suffixes=suffixes,
  --> 492             indicator=indicator,
      493         )
      494 

  ~/Documents/notebooks/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/multi.py in single_partition_join(left, right, **kwargs)
      321     # new index will not necessarily correspond the current divisions
      322 
  --> 323     meta = left._meta_nonempty.merge(right._meta_nonempty, **kwargs)
      324     kwargs["empty_index_dtype"] = meta.index.dtype
      325     name = "merge-" + tokenize(left, right, **kwargs)

  ~/Documents/notebooks/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in merge(self, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     7347             copy=copy,
     7348             indicator=indicator,
  -> 7349             validate=validate,
     7350         )
     7351 

  ~/Documents/notebooks/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
       79         copy=copy,
       80         indicator=indicator,
  ---> 81         validate=validate,
       82     )
       83     return op.get_result()

  ~/Documents/notebooks/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in __init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
      628         # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce
      629         # to avoid incompat dtypes
  --> 630         self._maybe_coerce_merge_keys()
      631 
      632         # If argument passed to validate,

  ~/Documents/notebooks/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _maybe_coerce_merge_keys(self)
     1136                     inferred_right in string_types and inferred_left not in string_types
     1137                 ):
  -> 1138                     raise ValueError(msg)
     1139 
     1140             # datetimelikes must match exactly

  ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

Presumably Dask is confused about the type of one of the columns, but I'm not sure which one. In particular I am not sure what the mention of a "int64" column in the error message is referring to.

The intermediary frame of mean vector values looks the same for both Pandas and Dask.

```
p.groupby("type")["vector"].apply(array_mean).to_frame().rename(columns={"vector":"mean"})
```

and

```
f.groupby("type")["vector"].apply(array_mean, meta="object").to_frame().rename(columns={0:"mean"}).compute()
```

both give

```
       mean
type
color  [0.8000000000000002, 0.9666666666666667]
shape  [0.9, 1.0]
```

Does anyone know how to make this work in Dask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you create the `means` dataframe - the index is an `int` and not an `str` (probably is a bug that is worth while to raise in github) (for some sort of reason - it may automatically be converted into a `categorical` type or something similar.)

In the mean time - below function is a work around.

```
def dask_ordering(f):
    means = f.groupby("type")["vector"].apply(array_mean, meta="object").to_frame(name="mean")    
    means['idx'] = means.index
    means['idx'] = means['idx'].astype(str)
    f = f.merge(means, left_on="type", right_on="idx")    
    f["cosine distance"] = f.apply(lambda row:cosine(row["vector"], row["mean"]), axis=1, meta="object")
    f.groupby("type", group_keys=False).apply(lambda x:x.sort_values("cosine distance"), meta="object")
    return f
```